# How to split a string from items in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, split

I want to split my string based on elements of a list but I am not sure how to do it.

```
    string = "IwenttotheParkToday"
    my_list = ["went", "the", "today"]
    
    Desired Output:
    [I, went, to, the, park, today]
```

Comment: *WHY* is that the desired output?  (That is, what is the logic the goes from those inputs to that output.)  And can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this?

Comment: Its just an example I have tried to use the re module but I have not been able to combine it with some sort of contains list

Comment: Why is `I` left capitalized but `Park` and `Today` are not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex, splitting on any of the words, and putting the split in a group so that it is kept in the output. We can also match in a case-insensitive way, using the `re.I` flag:

```
import re

string = "IwenttotheParkToday"
my_list = ["went", "the", "today"]

# we split on any of the words in my_list, and put it into a group 
# so that it is included in the output
split_re = re.compile('(' + '|'.join(my_list) + ')', re.I)
# the regex we use will be '(went|the|today)'

# we remove empty words if one of the split strings was at the start or end
out = [word for word in split_re.split(string) if word]

print(out)
# ['I', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'Park', 'Today']
```

Comment: You'd want to `re.escape()` each entry in the list in the more generic case.

Comment: why so complicated using regex?

Comment: Your output doesn't match what (stated) desired output is.

Comment: @Adrian: Maybe it is faster?

Comment: @Adrian: For a long `input`, sure.

Comment: It may not have worked with the example given above (i didnt test on that) but it worked on my actual code the example was given purely for direction

Answer (score 0):

Loop over `my_list` by using each element as the delimiter for `str.split()`:

```
input = "IwenttotheParkToday".lower() # make sure the casing matches
my_list = ["went", "the", "today"]

result = []

for current_delimiter in my_list:
  first, input = input.split(current_delimiter, maxsplit=2)
  result.extend((first, current_delimiter))

print(result) # prints ['i', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'park', 'today']
```

Comment: Your output doesn't match what desired output is.